# MvvmCross Android binding EditText in release mode

Tags: xamarin, binding, xamarin.android, linker, mvvmcross

I have a problem with binding EditText on Android platform.
Today I update in my project MvvmCross framework from 6.2.X to 6.3.1 (+ update others NuGets) and changed TargetSdk and CompileSdk from Android 8.1 to 9.0 and now when I have Release mode and linking set to "Sdk Assemblies" Only my app crash on View where I have binding EditText. In debug where I have checked "Use Shared Runtime" and set linking to "None" there is no problem it works.

I have Include TextView in LinkerPleaseInclude:

```
public void Include(TextView text)
{
    text.AfterTextChanged += (sender, args) => text.Text = $"{text.Text}";
    text.Hint = $"{text.Hint}";
}
```

it throws this exception: https://pastebin.com/EmkuL7hM

**Layout:**

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:paddingTop="50dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/backgroundColor">
       <LinearLayout
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center">
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/logo"
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_logo_red"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter" />
        </LinearLayout>
       <LinearLayout
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center">
            <TextView
                android:text="Email"
                local:MvxLang="Text Email"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@color/primaryColor"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_medium" />
            <EditText
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                local:MvxBind="Text LoginName"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:cursorVisible="true"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:textColorHint="@color/primaryTextColor"
                android:textColor="@color/primaryTextColor" /> 

            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center">
            <TextView
                android:text="Password"
                local:MvxLang="Text Password"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@color/primaryColor"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_medium" />
            <EditText
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                local:MvxBind="Text Password"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:cursorVisible="true"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:textColorHint="@color/primaryTextColor"
                android:textColor="@color/primaryTextColor" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center">
            <Button
                android:gravity="center"
                android:id="@+id/loginButton"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_large"
                local:MvxLang="Text Login"
                local:MvxBind="Click LoginCommand"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/button_round_primary"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:text="Login"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </LinearLayout> 
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

**ViewModel:**

```
  public class LoginViewModel : MvxViewModel
    {
        private readonly IMvxNavigationService _navigationService;
        private readonly IInfoMessageReporter _infoMessageReporter;
        private readonly ISessionInfo _session;
        private readonly ILoginService _loginService;
        private readonly IDataService _dataService;

        public LoginViewModel()
        {
            _navigationService = Mvx.IoCProvider.Resolve<IMvxNavigationService>();
            _infoMessageReporter = Mvx.IoCProvider.Resolve<IInfoMessageReporter>();
            _session = Mvx.IoCProvider.Resolve<ISessionInfo>();
            _loginService = Mvx.IoCProvider.Resolve<ILoginService>();
            _dataService = Mvx.IoCProvider.Resolve<IDataService>();

            RememberLogin = true;
        }

        public IMvxLanguageBinder TextSource => new MvxLanguageBinder(Constants.LocalizationNamespace, GetType().Name);

        public override async Task Initialize()
        {
            await InitializePermissionsAsync();
        }

        private async Task InitializePermissionsAsync()
        {
            // some stuff...
        }

        private string _password;
        public string Password
        {
            get => _password;
            set
            {
                _password = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(() => Password);
            }
        }

        private string _loginName;
        public string LoginName
        {
            get => _loginName;
            set
            {
                _loginName = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(() => LoginName);
            }
        }

        private MvxAsyncCommand _loginCommand;
        public IMvxAsyncCommand LoginCommand
        {
            get
            {
                _loginCommand = _loginCommand ?? new MvxAsyncCommand(async () => await ExecuteLoginAsync());
                return _loginCommand;
            }
        }

        private async Task ExecuteLoginAsync()
        {
            // some stuff....
        }
    }
```

Comment: You mention Edit text in your question, however, the code you show is for TextView. Do you have a similar method in LinkerPleaseInclude for EditText?

Comment: I tried create Include for EditText but I read it does not needed because EditText inherit from TextView. With Include for EditText there was same problem.

Comment: Can you post the code where you use the binding and the ViewModel?

Comment: I edited and added ViewModel and Layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the issue you are experiencing is a current bug in Xamarin's latest build (around Xamarin Android 9.4). This issue can be tracked [here](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/issues/3263) on GitHub.

---

The suggested workaround

> In case any other users come across this issue when using
>   Xamarin.Android 9.4, a possible workaround is to use a custom linker
>   configuration to preserve the missing types. To do that, add a new
>   `linker.xml` file to the project, set the Build Action to
>   `LinkDescription`, and add the XML lines to preserve the missing types.
>   For example, for the ITextWatcherInvoker error, add the following
>   lines to the file:
>
> ```xml
> <linker>
>  <assembly fullname="Mono.Android">
>    <type fullname="Android.Text.ITextWatcherInvoker" preserve="all" />
>  </assembly>
> </linker>
> ```